# insert multiple checkbox value using jquery and ajax but i only insert one record

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have this table in my database,

[image: see table image]

Now, in the raw_selected_rubric(Level) column that is where I will insert multiple values based on how many checkbox have been check.
For example,

[image: checkbox image]

Based on the picture I have selected the level 3 and level 4 and when I click submit only the level 3 value is inserted on my database.

[image: inserted checkbox]

Input field,

```
<input class="rubricChkbox" type="checkbox" value="3" />
```

Jquery and Ajax,

```
var rubricChkbox = [];
    $('.rubricChkbox').each(function(){  
            if($(this).is(":checked"))  
            {  
                 rubricChkbox.push($(this).val());  
            }  
       });  
       rubricChkbox = rubricChkbox.toString();
$.ajax({
        url: "Queries/save.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { 
              "rubricChkbox":rubricChkbox
              },
        success: function(yey){
          console.log(yey);
          alert(yey);
        }
      });
```

Queries/save.php,

```
if(isset($_POST['rubricChkbox'])) {
$rubric_value = $_POST['rubricChkbox'];

        $sql_raw = "INSERT INTO rubric_selected (raw_selected_rubric, Saved, ID_cmat, ID_users)

        VALUES  ('$rubric_value', '1')";

        $success = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_raw); 
}
```

What's wrong in my code? I'm sorry I'm still learning jquery and ajax. Thank you for the help.

What I want to happen is that if I selected Level 3 and 4 it both data will be inserted like this,

[image: expected output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to have multiple insert statements like this for example:

```
if(isset($_POST['rubricChkbox'])) {
$rubric_value = $_POST['rubricChkbox'];
    foreach($rubric_value as $value){
           $sql_raw = "INSERT INTO rubric_selected (raw_selected_rubric, Saved, ID_cmat, ID_users)

            VALUES  ('$value', '1')";

            $success = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_raw);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi sir, I've tried that and I'm getting an error  "<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: you need to remove this line from your jquery : rubricChkbox = rubricChkbox.toString();

Comment: from what I see all your checkboxes have the value of 3 : <input class="rubricChkbox" type="checkbox" value="3" /> you should give each a different value

Comment: I have fixed that sir. It actually work but the problem about it is that if i select level 3,4,5 it will insert levels 3 and 4 except the level 5.

Comment: I don't know about that probably it's an error in the html code

Comment: It's ok sir. Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help sir. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yep I've tried it sir,

```
if(isset($_POST['rubricChkbox'])) {
      $rubric_value = $_POST['rubricChkbox'];
      foreach($rubric_value as $value){

        $sql_raw = "INSERT INTO rubric_selected (raw_selected_rubric, Saved, ID_cmat, ID_users)

        VALUES  ('$value', '1')";

        $success = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_raw);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Hobbies = "";
$(".chkHobbies").each(function (e) {
  if (this.checked) {
    if (Hobbies == "") {
      Hobbies = this.id;
    } else {
      Hobbies = Hobbies + ',' + this.id;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: you need to have multiple insert statements like this for example:

Comment: Please add some explanations to your solution, and not just as comment but also in the answer (edit it)